# Arbitrary precision of square roots

Tags: python, math

I was quite disappointed when `decimal.Decimal(math.sqrt(2))` yielded

```
Decimal('1.4142135623730951454746218587388284504413604736328125')
```

and the digits after the 15th decimal place turned out wrong. (Despite happily giving you much more than 15 digits!)

How can I get the first `m` *correct* digits in the decimal expansion of `sqrt(n)` in Python?

Comment: To be clear, the loss of precision happens in `math.sqrt(2)`, which uses floating-point. Making it a `Decimal` afterwards doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use the [`sqrt` method on Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.sqrt)

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 100  # Change the precision
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try [bigfloat](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/). Example from the project page:

```
from bigfloat import *
sqrt(2, precision(100))  # compute sqrt(2) with 100 bits of precision
```

Answer (score 4):

IEEE standard double precision floating point numbers only have 16 digits of precision.  Any software/hardware that uses IEEE cannot do better:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

You'd need a special BigDecimal class implementation, with all math functions implemented to use it.  Python has such a thing:

https://literateprograms.org/arbitrary-precision_elementary_mathematical_functions__python_.html

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the first m correct digits in the decimal expansion of sqrt(n) in Python?

One way is to calculate [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) of the number multiplied by required power of 10. For example, using the Newton's method:

```
def isqrt(num):
    x = 1 << -(-num.bit_length() >> 1)  # ceil
    y = (x + num//x) >> 1
    while x > y:
        x = y
        y = (x + num//x) >> 1
    return x
```

Then to see the first 20 decimal places of `sqrt(2)`, you can do:

```
>>> num, prec = 2, 20
>>> isqrt(num * 10**(2*prec))
141421356237309504880
```

**Update**: Starting from Python 3.8, you can also use the [`math.isqrt()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt) function from the Standard Library.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what the `decimal` module is doing to compute `Decimal(2).sqrt()`. :-)

Comment: @Mark: Good to know. Although, last time I tried it, it was much slower than doing this "manually".

Comment: Yeah, the Python 2 decimal module was pure Python, and has never been known for its speed.  It should be a bit better in Python 3 (or using the `cdecimal` PyPI backport for Python 2).

Comment: @MarkDickinson you might be interested in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77295191/2599133) then which uses a very similar approach, but in base 2. Food for thought on adding something like this to `Fraction`... seems to be somewhat missing functionality 