# My Fibonacci generator is giving incorrect results

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

I am trying to work on a function which takes in a value `n` and outputs the `nth` number in the Fibonacci sequence. I have a looping function which seems to work like so:

```
def fibonacci_v1(n):
    a = b = 1
    for _ in range(1, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

and I am trying to work on a version which uses Binet's Formula as describes [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#:%7E:text=1%20Binet%27s%20Formula%20for%20the,(n%2D2)th.):

```
Phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2


def fibonacci_v2(n):
    c = pow(Phi, n)
    return math.floor((c - pow(-1, n) / c) / math.sqrt(5))
```

which seems to work for low values of `n` but breaks when a number is entered which is higher than 72... I suspect that this has to do with the accuracy of the `math.sqrt()` function but the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sqrt) doesn't say anything about its level of accuracy... is it the case that this is an issue with `math.sqrt` or is there something else wrong with my function?

For testing purposes I was using this for loop:

```
for x in range(1, 73):
    print(fibonacci_v1(x))
    print(fibonacci_v2(x))
```

Comment: This is incredibly close to a duplicate, but not quite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725522/arbitrary-precision-of-square-roots

Comment: @AdamSmith I think you are right... I will leave it open unless someone else closes it but it seems reasonable that it would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has less to do with `math.sqrt` than how the floating-point numbers are represented in python.
The default implementation

> Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”.

You can read more about the [limitation of in-built floating-point](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations) here.

You can use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module to take care of this inaccuracy

> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision

If you need even more accurate representation you can use [`getContext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial) to tweak the precision

```
from decimal import *
# Your Existing v1 implementation 
def fibonacci_v1(n):
    a = b = 1
    for _ in range(1, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

Phi = (1 + Decimal(5).sqrt()) / 2
# V2 implementation using the decimal module
def fibonacci_v2(n):
    getcontext().prec = 4096 # You need to tweak this number based on your precision requirements 
    c = Decimal(Phi) ** n
    fib = (c - (Decimal(-1)** n) / c) / Decimal(5).sqrt()
    return fib.quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_UP)


for x in range(73, 80):
    print(f"n={x}: v1={fibonacci_v1(x)}, v2={fibonacci_v2(x)}")
```

Output:

```
n=73: v1=806515533049393, v2=806515533049393
n=74: v1=1304969544928657, v2=1304969544928657
n=75: v1=2111485077978050, v2=2111485077978050
n=76: v1=3416454622906707, v2=3416454622906707
n=77: v1=5527939700884757, v2=5527939700884757
n=78: v1=8944394323791464, v2=8944394323791464
n=79: v1=14472334024676221, v2=14472334024676221
```

Comment: `decimal` is still floating point. It's just configurable-precision, decimal floating point. It's still subject to rounding error.

Comment: You are correct, I meant the in-built float precision isn't accurate. I'll reword it

Comment: This answer seems to have gotten me much farther at least (small hiccup at 465 but that may still be floating point accuracy)

Comment: After changing the accuracy that does seem to be the issue... I wonder if there'd be a way of having the accuracy scale as n increases...

Comment: @rpgstar You can configure the Decimal accuracy using for example `c=decimal.getcontext(); c.prec=1000` which gives you 1000 digits of precision.

Comment: @rpgstar as Mark suggested, `getcontext().prec = 4096`  would take care for n=465.
Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for speed and accuracy, use a Python generator instead.  Below calculates the first 10,000 Fibonacci numbers in five milliseconds, then calculates (but doesn't store) F<sub>0</sub> to F<sub>999,999</sub> in ~17s, and then prints the number of digits in F<sub>1,000,000</sub>.  Since this uses integer math instead of floating point, it is much faster and has no inaccuracies.

```
import time

def fib():
    a,b = 0,1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b,a+b

s = time.time()
it = fib()
f = [next(it) for _ in range(10000)] # list of F[0] - f[9999]
print(time.time() - s)

s = time.time()
it = fib()
for _ in range(1000000): # Skip over F[0]-F[999999]
    next(it)
print(time.time() - s)
print(len(str(next(it)))) # display no. of digits in F[1000000].

f = [next(it) for _ in range(10000)]
it = fib()
for _ in range(1000000): # Skip over F[0]-F[999999]
    next(it)
print(len(str(next(it)))) # display no. of digits in F[1000000].
```

Output:

```
0.005221128463745117
17.795812129974365
208988
```